# Which scriptures did rakshasa use to study?

Tags: scripture, rakshasa

What did the rakshasa use to study? Did they also have some kind of their own Veda? What did Ravana use to study?

Comment: Vedas. The guru of Asuras is Shukracharya.

Comment: 'Anu' tribe were Asuras. They used to read Vedas. Later after leaving India. They wrote Avesta.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment but Ravana, in particular, was well-versed in the [six shastras and the four Vedas](https://haribhakt.com/ravan-was-asur-but-taught-great-shiv-bhakti-to-bharatwasis/). He is even known to be an [excellent veena player](https://www.speakingtree.in/allslides/shocking-facts-about-ravana-no-one-knows/the-veena-maestro-347661). Therefore, we know that he was also trained in the arts.

Sources:

1. Prasad, B. A. "The Character of Ravana and Rama from the Buddhist Perspectives of the Ten Worlds." Language in India 11.5 (2011).
2. Sanmugeswaran, Pathmanesan, Krishantha Fedricks, and Justin W. Henry. "Reclaiming Ravana in Sri Lanka: Ravana’s Sinhala Buddhist Apotheosis and Tamil Responses." South Asia: Journal of South Asian Studies 42.4 (2019): 796-812.
3. Dirghangi, Aditi. "De-mythifying the Ramayana: A Study of the ‘Devoiced’Surpanakha." Proceeding of the International Conference on Arts and Humanities. Vol. 6. No. 1. 2019.

Comment: Welcome to HSE! Please support your answer with reference to reputed sources.

Comment: @Carmensandiego Thank you. I just added academic references.